# best way to loop through array object and group by in golang

Tags: arrays, go

I have a list of Books (BookId) and each book is associated to a Book collection (CollectionId).

I am trying to figure out the best way to group the results by Collection, so all the books that belong to a collection are listed under it and I can build the results in the following way:

Book A,D,G belong to Collection 1.
Book B,C,E belong to Collection 2.

I have the books in a list/array that I need to loop through and look up the collectionID they belong to and them need to store the new lists as seen below:

CollectionID 1:

```
- Book A, Book D, Book G
```

CollectionID 2:

```
- Book B, Book C, Book E
```

CollectionID 3:

```
- Book F
```

Comment: Can you show the `type` of the input and `Books` and other relevant data models?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a map to store a slice of books per collection ID.

```
type Book struct {
    Title        string
    Author       string
    CollectionID int
}

func main() {
    books := GetBooks()
    collections := make(map[int][]Book)
    for _, b := range books {
        collections[b.CollectionID] = append(collections[b.CollectionID], b)
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First, you design your database. For example,

```
package main

type CollectionId string

type Collection struct {
    Id   CollectionId
    Name string
}

type BookId string

type Book struct {
    Id         BookId
    Name       string
    Collection CollectionId
}

type Books map[BookId]Book

type Collections map[CollectionId][]BookId

func main() {}
```

Comment: Agreed, the db is the right place to do this, not in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Golang is really missing some helpers functions (such as Php `array_map` or Java `stream`), they want to keep it as simple as possible.

There is a library https://github.com/thoas/go-funk that provides "modern helpers (map, find, contains, filter, ...)", in your case, you could be interested by:

**ToMap**

> Transforms a slice of structs to a map based on a pivot field.

```
f := &Foo{
    ID:        1,
    FirstName: "Gilles",
    LastName:  "Fabio",
    Age:       70,
}

b := &Foo{
    ID:        2,
    FirstName: "Florent",
    LastName:  "Messa",
    Age:       80,
}

results := []*Foo{f, b}

mapping := funk.ToMap(results, "ID") // map[int]*Foo{1: f, 2: b}
```